# Sort Dict by order in list (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to convert a `dict` into an ordered `df`. The `dict` represents a `scatter plot`, which displays the coordinates in various `bins`.

Lets say `x,y lists` are as follows:

```
x = [10,40,33,44,66,77,33,44,55,2]
y = [1,4,53,34,56,47,83,44,25,12]
```

I sort the coordinates into appropriate bins with the output being:

```
bins =({
        1: [(10, 1), (2, 12)], 
        2: [(40, 4), (33, 53), (44, 34), (33, 83), (44, 44)], 
        3: [(66, 56), (55, 25)], 
        4: [(77, 47)]
        })
```

If I convert to a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(bins, orient = 'index')
d = df.transpose()
```

Output:

```
         1         2         3         4
0  (10, 1)   (40, 4)  (66, 56)  (77, 47)
1  (2, 12)  (33, 53)  (55, 25)      None
2     None  (44, 34)      None      None
3     None  (33, 83)      None      None
4     None  (44, 44)      None      None
```

What I'm hoping to do is order the `df` by order in the `list`, so I'd like the output to be:

```
         1          2        3        4
0   (10, 1)         
1              (40, 4)      
2             (33, 53)          
3             (44, 34)      
4                               (66, 56)
5                               (77, 47)
6             (33, 83)      
7             (44, 44)      
8                      (55, 25) 
9   (2, 12)
```

I not sure if this can be done. So I'm thinking of trying to return the bin No. for each scatter point at each index:

```
   Bin
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    4
5    4
6    2 
7    2
8    3
9    1
```

I have tried `collections.OrderedDict` but I need to order by index not by `keys`.

I'm not sure if I could make the input a list of lists?

Comment: Numpy.histogram2d?

Comment: To create and return bins?

Comment: And do the binning

Comment: I didn't want to confuse the readers. The `bins` are irregular sizes. Essentially two `arcs`. Traditional grid isn't applicable

Answer (score 1):

*skipping over the pandas part*

`b = collections.OrderedDict(bins) #Resort by order in list`

collections.OrderedDict does not sort the value given in the constructor. it simply preserves the order in which the dict was created.

if you need to re-order the dict and preserve the order of it, then you will need to sort the bins (based on your requirements) and then pass it on to an ordered dict

as an example; if you like to sort the `bins` on the key,

```
b = collections.OrderedDict()
for k in sorted(bins):
    b[k] = bins[k]
```